# How do I link a toggle event to a single bootstrap collapse heading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

basically want to toggle the visibility of a separate element by linking up with the toggling of a bootstrap-collapsed heading.  in the case below, the clicking of "#producer" will expand/collapse "#collapseOne".  i want that same function to make ".cv" appear and disappear too.  i don't want other headings to affected, though, so it should be specific to just clicking "#producer".

markup:

```
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" id="producer">Producer Reel <em>For Hire!</em>
    </a>
    <a class="cv" href="#">
      <i class="icon-file-text-alt"></i>my CV
    </a> 
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">...</div>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){    
   $(this).next('.cv').collapse('toggle');
});
```

Comment: @user2031099 please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved.  Thanks